# Unit Not Found after daemon-reload

Tags: services, systemctl

My service is running as expected, I can start, top, restart, status. But if I run `systemctl daemon-reload`, running `systemctl start`, `stop`, and `status` for my services results in the error:

```
Failed to restart <my_service>.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.
```

`systemctl status <service>` shows:

```
● gunicorn.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: Unit gunicorn.service not found.)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-31 18:14:24 EDT; 1min 51s ago
```

Once I stop the service and restart, all is fine.

Comment: Discovered the issue is related to deploying the service as a symlink in `/etc/systemd/system`. If its not a symlink, there are no issues. Also, when using symlink, `enable` fails with error: `Failed to enable unit: File <service_name>.service: Link has been severed`